# How do I filter a Pandas DataFrame based on values in many, many columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame called df with over 40,000 rows and 90+ columns.

Here's a snippet of what it looks like:

```
p1 p2 p3 p4 value 
0  1  0  1   5
1  0  1  0   4
1  1  0  0   6
0  1  0  1   2
```

I would like to be able to find the sum of 'value' for unique combinations of p1,p2,p3,p4. So when p2=1 and p4=1 (there are always exactly two 1s in each set of p1,p2,p3,p4), the sum of their 'value' column would be 7 in this case. This is easy to find with `df[(df.p2 == 1) & (df.p4 == 1)].value.sum()`.

However, I have no idea how to do this for *my* DataFrame df because of how large it is. Instead of p1-p4, it consists of p1-p89.

My initial idea was to create a new column with the values of the 89 columns I want to filter by:

```
unique_list = []
for n in range(0,df.shape[0]):
    unique_list.append(str(df.values[n][1:90]))
df['identifier'] = unique_list
```

Each row would then have an identifier for those 89 values, so I could just sort based on that row. However, this is taking quite a long time. I estimated that this for loop will take about 40 minutes to run through. That's not unbearably long -- by the time I finish submitting this question, it's probably going to be close to complete. But for the sake of learning, I can't help but think that there must be a more efficient method for accomplishing this.

So, is there? And is there a way for me to do it without needing to create a new identifier column?

If it matters, my end goal is to create a new DataFrame in which the number of rows is the number of unique combinations of p1-p89. The 'value' column in the new DataFrame will be the sum of the 'value' column for all the instances of that combination in the previous DataFrame, and there will be a new find the sum of the 'value' column for each unique combination of p1-p89.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you could do this with a `groupby`.

```py
# Get everything except the value column.
group_cols = [o for o in df.columns if o != 'value']

# Group into unique combinations, sum the value column.
unique_counts = df.groupby(group_cols).sum().reset_index()
```